# What is the minimal polynomial equation with integral coefficients that the area of the regular 11-gon with side lengths 1 satisfies?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Let $q_n(x)$ be the minimal polynomial for the area of the regular $n$-gon. What is $q_{11}(x)$?

The following are the simpler cases, and $x$ is given by $16 (area^2) $:

For the corresponding triangle the polynomial is $p_3(x) = x-3$, for the square it is $p_4(x) = x - 16$, for the pentagon it is $p_5(x) = x^2-50x+125$, for the hexagon it is $p_6(x) =x-108$.

What is e.g.  $p_{11} (x)$? What is $p_n(x)$ in general? The question follows from a discussion on the Robbins' formula: http://youtu.be/OeZ6LsZHKcA

Robbins' formulas are meant to generalize Heron's and Brahmagrupta's formula to general cyclic n-gons (convex and concave alike). So far the formulas for n up to 9 have been discovered. A viewer of that video suggested we can do regular n-gons first. So for the pentagon case, if  you substitute all five $distance^2$ with 1, then you will  have the following factorized form: $(x^2-50x+125)(x-3)^5 = 0$. This is the same as $p_5(x)(p_3(x))^5 = 0$.  This 5 is a result from combinatoric arguments on  the degenerate cases: http://youtu.be/alFkaEZ4cZQ

So how do you generalize?

Comment: It would be good to link to whatever video you're referencing and state the formula you're referring to. It would also be good to state an explicit question rather than a general topic.

Comment: Made the question much more specific.

Comment: Question still unclear. There is a regular 11-gon of area 17; that area satisfies the polynomial equation $x-17=0$. What do you really mean? Also, $\sin(2\pi/11)$ can certainly be expressed using $n$th roots, in particular, $44$th roots of unity. What do you really mean?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the area of a regular $n$-gon with side length $1$ equals $\frac n4 \cot \frac\pi n$. The OP's $x$ is thus $n^2\cot^2 \frac\pi n$.

Comment: Yes but I want to do something more algebraic. I am using the spread polynomials $s_n(x^2) = T_n(x)^2$. Then each distinct of $s_n(x) = 0$ corresponds to  one distinct roots of the equation $R(x) = 0$, the Robbins equation applied to the regular n-gon with side lengths 1.

Comment: The $T_n(x)$ is the Chebyshev polynomials. I want to use the recurrence relation of the spread polynomials to see if I can write down the recurrence relation of the $R_n(x)$.

Comment: So, assuming @Greg is right (a safe assumption, in my experience), you are asking for the minimal polynomial for $121\cot^2(\pi/11)$ or, more generally, $n^2\cot^2(\pi/n)$. I'm pretty sure this kind of thing is in the literature, and I'd start by looking for papers of Niven on minimal polynomials for (special values of) trig functions. You might be able to dig something out of the links at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6497268 (I haven't looked at it in detail).

Comment: In my view $p_3(x)=16x^2-3$, $\>p_4(x)=x-1$. – Make "with side length $1$" a part of the text body, not of the title.

Comment: I got the formula of the 16*(area)^2 of a regular n-gon as $$(2n\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))^2$$  This may be different from the formula given by Greg (?). Perhaps I am wrong and get therefore some unexplainable minimal polynomials. In any case the $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ is dealt with in the Niven book on Irrational Numbers on p. 37 as Gerry said. Alas I know no further articles of Niven on the subject.

Comment: A remark concerning a calculation I did: the minimal polynomial of $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ is e.g $\frac{T_5(x)}{x}$. This is perhaps true für all odd natural numbers $n$. At least a connection to the theory of Prof Wildbergers spread polynomials user wilsonw prefers.

Comment: Another formula for the minimal polynomial of $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ for odd n is conjectured to be $$(x-i\sqrt{1-x^2})^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}\Phi_n(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2})$$ with the Euler $\phi$ function and the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$

Comment: @Wolfgang, if the side length is $1$ then you can split the polygon, by lines from the center to the vertices, into $n$ isosceles triangles, each with base $1$ and opposite angle $2\pi/n$. Each such triangle can be split, by a perpendicular bisector of the base, into two right triangles, each with a side $1/2$ and opposite angle $\pi/n$. Let the other side of the triangle be $x$. Then $\tan(\pi/n)=(1/2)/x$, so $x=(1/2)\cot(\pi/n)$, so area of triangle is $(1/8)\cot(\pi/n)$, so area of polygon is $(n/4)\cot(\pi/n)$, so $16{\rm area}^2=n^2\cot^2(\pi/n)$, as Greg wrote.

Comment: I asked Maple for the minimal polynomial for $\cot(\pi/11)$, and it gave me $x^5+x^4-12x^3-15x^2+18x-6$, which is plausible. But then I asked for minimal polynomial for $121\cot^2(\pi/11)$, and it gave me $4x^4-5613x^3-1089x^2+4841x-3141$, which looks very wrong.

Comment: @Gerry, your formula is not the one for the n-gon in the unit circle I think. Your formula is the one for the inner radius equal to 1 according to the Wikipedia article on regular polygons. Please check.

Comment: @wolfgang, the formula is for the polygon with sides of length 1, which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the [area $A$ of regular $n$-gon with side-length $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area), we have
$$A = \frac{n}{4} \cot\frac{\pi}{n} \qquad\to\qquad \cos^2\frac{\pi}{n}= \frac{x}{x+n^2}$$
where $x := 16 A^2$. The [Chebyshev polynomial $T_n(\cdot)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) is such that 
$$T_n(\cos(\pi/n)) = \cos(\pi) = -1$$
Therefore, finding a (not-necessarily-*minimal*) polynomial satisfied by $x$ is a matter of eliminating $c := \cos(\pi/n)$ from the polynomial system
$$\begin{align}
(x+n^2)\;c^2 - x &= 0 \tag{1}\\[4pt]
T_n(c)+1 &= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
A computer algebra system can do this readily; *Mathematica*, for instance, has a `Resultant[]` command for this purpose. The general theory of resultants is a bit of computational overkill here, though. We can use $(1)$ to reduce $(2)$ to a *linear* equation in $c$, say $P c + Q = 0$; then we can write $c^2 = \frac{Q^2}{P^2}$, so that $P^2 x - Q^2 ( x + n^2 )$ gives the target polynomial. (Of course, unless/until a closed form is determined, the brute-force symbol manipulation remains something to be done with a CAS.)

These are the results of the brute-force operation ...

> `Factor[Resultant[ ChebyshevT[n,c] + 1, (x+n^2)c^2 - x, c ]]`

... performed by *Mathematica* for various $n$ (with extraneous factors and powers left in for completeness):
$$\begin{align}
n = 3 &: \quad 81\;(x - 3)^2 \\[4pt]
n = 4 &: \quad 4\;(x - 16)^4 \\[4pt]
n = 5 &: \quad 625\;(x^2 - 50 x + 125)^2 \\[4pt]
n = 6 &: \quad 4x^2\;(x-108)^4 \\[4pt]
n = 7 &: \quad 2401\;(x^3 - 245 x^2 + 7203 x - 16807)^2 \\[4pt]
n = 8 &: \quad 4\;(x^2 - 384 x + 4096)^4 \\[4pt]
n = 9 &: \quad 6561(x-27)^2\;(x^3 - 729 x^2 + 72171 x -177147)^2 \\[4pt]
n = 10 &: \quad 4 x^2\;(x^2 - 1000 x + 50000 )^4 \\[4pt]
n = 11 &: \quad 14641\;\left(\;
\begin{array}{c}
x^5 - 1815 x^4 + 614922 x^3 \\
- 53146830 x^2 + 1071794405 x - 2357947691  \\
\end{array}\;\right)^2 \\[4pt]
n = 12 &: \quad 4 (x - 144)^4\;(x^2 - 2016 x + 20736)^4 \\[4pt]
n = 13 &: \quad 28561\;\left(\;
\begin{array}{c}
x^6 - 3718 x^5 + 2827539 x^4 - 637138788 x^3 \\
+ 44865189655 x^2 - 827150951094 x + 1792160394037  
\end{array}
\;\right)^2
\end{align}$$

---

**Edit.** Since $n$ itself is part of the elimination process, it figures into the result(ant)s in ways that the above doesn't make clear. Here are the interesting factors, using explicit references to powers of $n$ among the coefficients.

$$\begin{align}
n = 3 &: \quad x - n \\[4pt]
n = 4 &: \quad x - n^2 \\[4pt]
n = 5 &: \quad x^2 - 2 n^2 x + n^3 \\[4pt]
n = 6 &: \quad x - 3 n^2 \\[4pt]
n = 7 &: \quad x^3 - 5 n^2 x^2 - 3 n^4 x - n^5 \\[4pt]
n = 8 &: \quad x^2 - 6 n^2 x + n^4 \\[4pt]
n = 9 &: \quad x^3 - n^3 x^2 + 11 n^4 x - 3 n^5 \\[4pt]
n = 10 &: \quad x^2 - n^3 x + 5 n^4 \\[4pt]
n = 11 &: \quad x^5 - 15 n^2 x^4 + 42 n^4 x^3 - 30 n^6 x^2 + 5 n^8 x - n^9 \\[4pt]
n = 12 &: \quad x^2 - 14 n^2 x + n^4 \\[4pt]
n = 13 &: \quad x^6 - 22 n^2 x^5 + 99 n^4 x^4 - 132 n^6 x^3 + 55 n^8 x^2 - 6 n^{10} x + n^{11}  
\end{align}$$

It may be worth noting that $11$ is a common factor of most of the coefficients in the $n=13$ polynomial, and $3$ is a common factor in half of the coefficients in the $n=11$ polynomial.

It may also be worth noting that the degree of $n$ in the polynomials gives the sequence
$$1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 9, 4, 11, ...$$
which is an offset of [OEIS's A216475](http://oeis.org/A216475): "The number of numbers coprime to and less than $n$, excluding 2." (The OEIS sequence begins at index $1$, so its reference to $n+2$ corresponds to our use of $n$ here.) The pattern continues through at least $n=25$ with minor fiddling in the cases of $n=15$, $21$, and $25$: in these cases, the power of $n$ is too big by $1$; we can "fix" that by writing, $n^{p+1}$ as $n\cdot n^p$ and treating the pulled-off $n$ as "just a number". (In the case of $n=25$, writing $n^{20}$ as $25n^{19}$ allows us to divide the polynomial by its leading $x$-coefficient, $5$, making it monic in $x$.)

By the way, the degree sequence for $x$ ...
$$1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, ...$$
... appears as an offset of [OEIS's A023022](http://oeis.org/A023022): the "half-totient" function, $\phi(n)/2$.

---

**Edit 2.** We can use this [explicit formula for $T_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions) ...
$$T_n(c) = c^n\;\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}(1-c^{-2})^k$$
... to give formulas for the polynomials above (the ones with the extra factors and powers; determining the minimal polynomial from these is an exercise for the reader).

When $n=2m$, there's no appreciable work, since $c$ appears in even powers throughout, and $(2)$ simply becomes (after clearing denominators)
$$\left(x+n^2\right)^m + \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{2k}(-1)^k x^{m-k} n^{2k}$$

When $n=2m+1$, there's an extra power of $c$, so our manipulations involve squaring to get
$$\left(x+n^2\right)^{n} - x\;\left(\;\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{2k}(-1)^k x^{m-k} n^{2k} \; \right)^2 $$

Comment: Please give a hint how you calculated the general formulas of the "interesting factors" in your "Edit" section above.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: At this point, I'm afraid I don't remember much about what I was thinking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edited and corrected

If I set $$\kappa_n(x)=(x-i\sqrt{1-x^2})^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}\Phi_n(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2})$$ and then calculate $$f_n(x)=\kappa_{4n}(\frac{x}{2n})\kappa_{4n}(-\frac{x}{2n})$$ then I get at least for odd primes $n$ $$f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}}{n^{\phi(n)}}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}(x^2-(2n\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))^2)$$ So the 16*area^2 should be a root of $f(\sqrt{x})$. I have not yet done some CAS program checks though.

The correction is necessary as then $\frac{\phi(4n)}{2}=\phi(n)$ and so $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial then because of the degree correpondence of the cyclotomic polynomials. I will test this for e.g. n=5 asap.

**Edit 1** The product formula for $f_n(x)$ above is for $n=p$ odd prime. For odd $n$
I set $E_n=\{k|1\le k<n,\ \text{k being coprime to $n$}\ (k,,)=1\}$ and then ( not yet fully proved ) $$f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}}{n^{\phi(n)}}\prod_{k\in E_n}(x^2-(2n\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))^2)$$
**Edit 2** I hope to have proved correctly that $\kappa_{4n}(x)$ is an even polynomial. So it results in $$f_n(x)=\kappa_{4n}^2(\frac{x}{2n})$$ being a square of the irreducible polynomial.

**Edit 3** Please excuse that I work contrary to the problem posted on the case with the n-gon lying on the unit circle. Just now I dont know whether there are connections to the case of side length 1. I hope to be able to give further results on my work if available.

Comment: I checked the case n=5 with Maple. Its OK. I got $$f_5(x)=25 - 2 x^2  + 7/125 x^4  - 2/3125 x^6  + 1/390625 x^8$$ which is factorized to $$1/390625 (3125 - 125 x^2  + x^4 )^2$$ One root y=x^2 is $\frac{25}{2}(5+\sqrt{5})$ which according to formulas in Wikepedia for outer radius 1 is exactly the 16*(area)^2. qed.

Comment: May I know who made this conjecture and how did he/she come up with this formula?

Comment: I did and I am working on the general case for even n too. But this will be much harder. The original idea goes back to the work of Mr. Heierman who defined some valuable polynomials in his article on his Website. I just hacked the case n=17 : quite correcly in the set of roots of $$827240261886336764177 - 34349076618117789516 x  + 415992277382049354 x^2 - 2261945156303778 x^3 + 6522333207335 x^4  - 10668805498 x^5   + 9938999 x^6   - 4913 x^7   + x^8$$ appears the value for the quadrea $$150.8528458464590309956191688936093948707676158087195160151694...$$ Mathematica doesnt show radicals.

Comment: Would you mind posting the link to the website so I could have an idea why this formula works?

Comment: I suppose you want the paper of William E Heierman. But be prepared that it is not immediately clear how I came to the formula. It took me a while to analyze his work. Here 2 links ( one in French ) 1. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynôme_minimal_des_valeurs_spéciales_trigonométriques 2. http://www.corunduminium.com/Trigpolys.html Hope it helps to understand how it fits all together.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: In case you are interested, the root $x = 150.8528\dots$ is a root of, $$x^2-17^2\left(\frac{17-\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{2(17-\sqrt{17})}}{4}\right)x+17^4\left(\frac{17-3\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{2(85-19\sqrt{17})}}{4}\right)=0$$ hence can be expressed in real radicals.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III Impressive. Any hint about the method you got this quadratic equation ? I have not hte faintest idea how that comes about. Thanks for your interest and work.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: You can actually let _Mathematica_ do this. Let your octic be $P(x)=0$. Use the command $Solve[P(x)==0,x]$. Mathematica will give you eight _root objects_ $x_i$. Assume that $x_1 = 150.8528\dots$. Then use $a=RootReduce[x_1+x_n]$ and $b=RootReduce[x_1x_n]$ for some $n$. For the appropriate $n$ (there are only seven choices), then $a,b$ reduces to quartics. So finally, $$x^2-ax+b = 0$$ where one of the roots of the quadratic is $x=x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I also did work on the case of the side of the polygonal being equal to 1. My results agree with the ones given by user Blue. I use the polynomial given as

$$p_n(x)=\Phi_n(1)\prod_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^{n}(x-\cot(\frac{k\pi}{n}))$$

Then one gets the expression/"interesting factors" of user Blue when one calculates

$$n^{\phi(n)}p_n(\frac xn)$$

where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function and $\Phi_n(x)$ the n-th cyclotomic polynomial.